# command line recursive word-based diff?

Tags: word-diff

is there a command line program that gives recursive word-based diff (on 2 directories)?

`diff -u` is recursive, but it doesn't do word by word comparison. `wdiff` and `dwdiff` does word based diff but there are not built-in options for recursive diff.

I would like to pipe the result to `colordiff` so a program that generates output that `colordiff` understands would be especially useful. Any suggestions? Thanks!

CC

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question (hence posting as a comment), but if you're on a system with a GUI then it might be easier to use a GUI diff program. I find meld (http://meld.sourceforge.net/) to be quite good.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Git can do it and output color:

The following often works:

```
git diff --color-words path1 path2
```

but in general you may need to do

```
git diff --no-index --color-words path1 path2
```

Neither file even needs to be in a git repository!

`--no-index` is needed if you and the paths are in a git working tree. It can be elided if you or one of the files are outside a git working tree.

Manpage: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/1.8.5 (and later...)

> **git diff --no-index [--options] [--] […​]**
>
> This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can
>   omit the --no-index option when running the command in a working tree
>   controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the
>   working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree
>   controlled by Git.

Comment: +1 - I never knew you could use git diff on files outside a repo. Thanks.

Comment: Great idea if both inputs are files, but what if one input is the output of a command? `-` isn't accepted as a directive to use stdin. I tried Bash process substitution (`git diff --no-index -- <(echo foo quux baz) somefile`), but apparently `git-diff-file` doesn't read from a named pipe but instead prints the "contents" as `pipe:[3377923]` or similar.

Comment: @cjs If your commands take a file as input, you may be able to use textconv.  For example, I wanted to run `git diff ... <(gzip -dc foo.gz) <(gzip -dc bar.gz)`.  I was able to achieve this by adding `*.gz diff=gz` to .gitattributes, adding `[diff "gz"]` ` textconv=gzip -dc` to .gitconfig, and running `git diff --textconv ... foo.gz bar.gz`